# label not fully on page

Tags: html, css

I'm having a small problem with a hover aria label I made with HTML/CSS. As you can see in the picture below, the title is not fully shown on the page. When the sentence is too long, I want the rest of the sentence shown on a new line so you can still read it. Can someone help?
[image]

```css
span:hover {
    position: relative;
}

span[aria-label]:hover:after {
    content: attr(aria-label);
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 20px;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #00adf6;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span aria-label="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc consequat diam nec ullamcorper dapibus. Sed nunc odio, accumsan id pellentesque in, interdum quis metus."><i class="fa fa-info info-btn"></i></span>
```

Adding a `width` or `max-width` didn't work.

The first problem is now solved. But now I have the following problem:
[image]

Other text is going over it. I want the aria-label to be on the foreground.

Comment: Use this prop   word-wrap: normal;

Comment: white-space: nowrap; <-- well you do not want to wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove

white-space: nowrap;

add `display:block` for showing it properly or you can use `div` tag instead if `span`

```css
span:hover {
    position: relative;
    display: block; /*added*/

}

span[aria-label]:hover:after {
    content: attr(aria-label);
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 20px;
    top: 100%;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #00adf6;
    background: #FFF; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span  aria-label="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc consequat diam nec ullamcorper dapibus. Sed nunc odio, accumsan id pellentesque in, interdum quis metus."><i class="fa fa-info info-btn"></i></span>
```

Comment: This works! But now it's very small and I can't fix it and it's getting behind other divs

Answer (score 1):

Delete `white-space:nowrap`

It means that you dont allow sentence to break to another line.
Default value is `white-space:normal`

Answer (score 1):

Under `span[aria-label]:hover:after`

Remove `white-space:nowrap` or change it to `white-space:normal`

Comment: This works! But now it's very small and I can't fix it and it's getting behind other divs

Comment: z-index can help for the 'getting behind other divs' part.

Answer (score 1):

```css
span:hover {
    position: relative;
}

span[aria-label]:hover:after {
    content: attr(aria-label);
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: normal;
    left: 20px;
    top: 0; /* new **/
    min-width: 200px;  /* new **/
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #00adf6;
    background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span aria-label="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc consequat diam nec ullamcorper dapibus. Sed nunc odio, accumsan id pellentesque in, interdum quis metus."><i class="fa fa-info info-btn"></i></span>
```